# Android - map a string to different value

Tags: android, makefile

I would like to map a string variable to different value! for example:

```
VAR := valid value is "user" or "userdebug"

VAR1 := VAR convert to "release" or "debug"
VAR2 := VAR convert to "Release" or "Debug"
```

I do not like if else, how can we do it just one line code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
VAR := valid value is "user" or "userdebug"

VAR1 := $(if $(filter $(VAR),user),release,debug)
VAR2 := $(if $(filter $(VAR),user),Release,Debug)
```